# Eclipse - Project specific PHP code style formatter

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-pdt

In Eclipse if you select Window > Preferences > PHP > Code Style > Formatter, you can select an Active Profile, e.g. PHP conventions or Zend Framework. How can you set this for a specific project?

If you go into 'Configure Project Specific Settings' then all you can specify are text encoding and delimiters, not the formatting profile to be used.

[image: PHP Code Style Formatter]

Installed software:

[image: Installed Software]

**UPDATE 16/07/2014**: I have since upgraded to Eclipse Luna (4.4) and things appeared to be better, in that having selected 'Configure Project Specific Settings' and selected a project, you can now select a code formatter. However, it doesn't actually save the preference and the project continues to use the overall workspace setting. You can also see that if you select 'show only projects with project specific settings' then no projects will be shown.

Comment: Did you try opening the project's properties via right-click? All project-specific settings are configurable there.

Comment: I should have mentioned that already tried opening project's properties via right-click but for some reason php/code style/formatter doesn't appear in my menu.

Comment: Is the project defined as PHP Project? Is the option `PHP` available in project properties?

Comment: Yes, project is defined as a PHP project.

Answer (score 0):

Further investigation shows that the update to Eclipse 'Luna' (4.4) has allowed me to now set a project specific formatter. The only remaining problem seems to be that when the 'show only projects with project specific settings' checkbox is checked it doesn't show any projects, even though settings have been saved. I've raised an Eclipse Bugzilla issue for this.

Comment: please post the link to the Bugzilla issue